# Node.js and javascript interpreter different?

Tags: javascript, node.js

For below code, in Javascript i got output : *The Window*

```
var name = "The Window";
var object = {
　　　name : "My Object",
　　    　getNameFunc : function(){
　　　　    　return function(){
　　　　　　    　return this.name;
　　　    　　};
　　　    }
　    };
console.log(object.getNameFunc()());
```

but for Node.js , i got below output : undefined

i was confused that , is Node.js use the difference interpreter with javascript?

Answer (score 4):

> In browsers, the top-level scope is the global scope. That means that
>   in browsers if you're in the global scope var something will define a
>   global variable.

So in the global scope, when you run `var name = "The Window";`, it is same with `window.name = "The window";`.

> In Node this is different. The top-level scope is not the global
>   scope; var something inside a Node module will be local to that
>   module.

That's the reason you can't get `name` in nodejs.

Comment: You mean that scope for inner function (returning this.name) is 'global' and not the 'top-level'?

Comment: Understood - as module is wrapped with another function, 'top-level' is closure scope.

Comment: Per my understanding , the name and the function is in the same module , because they are in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

`this` points to the owner which makes the call. In your example, since you used the self executing function `object.getNameFunc()()`, then the owner is the `window` object in the browser.

In node, if you run it in the node console, you will see 'The Window', if you run the script using the command `>node xxx.js`, you will see `undefined`.